# how to optimize the time in executing the query in c# react

Tags: c#, sql, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am new to React and new to Web API. I am uploading data in a tabulator in react front end from the value that I am passing through the web API. I am passing value through the getReports function like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetReports")]
public IHttpActionResult GetReports(string jwt, List<object> data)
{
    if (!Common.VerificationToken.VerifyJWToken(jwt))
    {
        return null;
    }
    var to = data[0];
    var from = data[1];
    DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(to);
    DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(from);

    var ReportData = db.T_CQL_COIL_DESC.Where(t => t.CCD_CREATED_ON >= toDate && 
        t.CCD_CREATED_ON <= fromDate).ToList();




    ReportsDTO dto = new ReportsDTO();
    List<ReportsDTO> ReportDTO = new List<ReportsDTO>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var report in ReportData)
        {
            List<vehicledetail> vehicle = new List<vehicledetail>();
            var imgurl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty- 
            monitoring-dev.appspot.com/";
            dto = new ReportsDTO();
            dto.Type = report.CCD_OP_TYPE;
            dto.ID = report.CCD_COIL_ID;
            vehicle = GetVehicleID(dto.ID);
            vehicledetail vehicledetails = vehicle[0];
            dto.vehicleno = vehicledetails.vehicleno.ToString();
            dto.wagonno = vehicledetails.wagonno.ToString();
            dto.Active = report.CCD_ACTIVE;
            dto.ImgURL = report.CCD_IMAGE_URL != null ? imgurl + report.CCD_IMAGE_URL : "NA";
            dto.Desc = report.CCD_VIEW_DESC != null ? report.CCD_VIEW_DESC : "NA";
            ReportDTO.Add(dto);
        }

        return Ok(ReportDTO);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Something went wrong");
    }


}
```

The data in vehicledetail in vehicledetail vehicledetails = vehicle[0]; is getting populated from this function:

```
public List<vehicledetail> GetVehicleID(string coilID)
{
    List<vehicledetail> vehicle = new List<vehicledetail>();
    vehicledetail vehicledetails = new vehicledetail();

    string oradb = Utilities.STAR_DB;
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);


    string query = "SELECT a.Vbeln, b.WAGON_NO FROM sapr3.lips a, sapr3.ZVTRRDA b WHERE 
    a.MANDT='600' AND a.CHARG='" + coilID + "' AND a.LFIMG > 0 AND a.MANDT = b.MANDT AND 
    a.VBELN = b.VBELN";


    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {

        vehicledetails.vehicleno = row["VBELN"].ToString();
        vehicledetails.wagonno = row["WAGON_NO"].ToString();
    }

    conn.Close();
    vehicle.Add(vehicledetails);

    return (vehicle);

}
```

It is working fine but it is taking 30 seconds to load the below data:

[image]

How do I optimize this . Please help. Note: that it is taking 30 seconds to upload this data

Comment: On a side note, try to use parametrized queries. Building a DB query using string concatenation may be - and often is - a vulnerability.

Comment: can you give an example of that

Answer (score 0):

Few other things aside, the major problem seems to be that you are querying database for each vehicle.

1. In this particular scenario it might very well be better to select all vehicle ids and query them all.

   var vehicleIds = reportData.SelectMany(t => t.ID);

You can then form a query that will get all vehicle details together. This will reduce the number of database calls and it can have massive impact on time.

2. Another thing to check is if there's any index created on the vehicle id column in database as that may also help speed things up.

Comment: can you give an example of that given in the code